# Как вывести всплывающее окно при прерывании события CRM bitrix24?

Tags: php, битрикс, битрикс24

Отслеживаю событие OnBeforeCrmContactAdd, событие отслеживается нормально, условия внутри функции выполняются корректно. При определенном условии, нужно вывести в CRM всплывающее окно с описанием, подскажите как это сделать

скрипт отслеживания события:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

файл кастомного логирования:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

само представление в CRM:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Задал этот вопрос в техподдержку битрикса.

Ответ:

Добрый день. Штатно такой функционал не предусмотрен.
С этим вопросом Вы можете обратиться к партнерам, которые оказывают услуги по внедрению, настройке и доработке Битрикс24 под индивидуальные запросы клиентов. Просто заполните вот эту форму: *ссылка на форму*, и наши партнеры сами свяжутся с Вами.

Нашел только один способ вывода теста.

при добавлении текста в $arFields['RESULT_MESSAGE'], этот текст выводится в описании ошибки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]